# Why .htaccess is not wroking to removing index.php?url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to remove the index.php?url=controller/method/parem
I just want to remove the index.php?url= thats it but its not working.

Now its look like this :
http://localhost/ServerSide/index.php?url=FrameWork/Index/category

I want
http://localhost/ServerSide/FrameWork/Index/category

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

Comment: I assume that you are using Codeigniter as your framework so you have to follow these steps 1) in your config folder edit the config.php and change this  ` $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; `  to ` $config['index_page'] = ''; ` then in root folder create a file .htaccess and paste that code  ` RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] ``` after that everywhere in your application use ```php base_url() ``` function to create links on a side note if you still access with index.php it will be accessible

Comment: its my own mvc pattern not codeigniter f.....                      https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VY8hFN80SEAkjpzPhPYe3ZYPVsxYaevM

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CodeIgniter then this solution works for me. 
https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-htaccess-remove-index-php/

Comment: Sorry, Its not Codeigniter

Comment: And apart from that link-only "answers" are not exactly well received here on SO. Please post _real_ answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is roughly what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?ServerSide/(.*)$ /ServerSide/index.php?url=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported [END] flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older [L] flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's DOCUMENT_ROOT folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I was download the apache 1 week ago new version php version also new all new

Comment: @MdTahazzot Sorry, but I have no idea what you are trying to tell me by that comment.